# For Loop with a named object

Tags: vba, for-loop, label, ms-word

I have 200 Labels (Legacy Control Tool) that I have linked to an excel spreadsheet. I would like to use a For Loop to populate those 200 labels without writing 200 lines of code for each, individually named label.

Currently, I am using the following line of code to bring in the excel cell data:
ThisDocument.A0.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1)

I would like to iterate the "A0" portion (which is the name of 1 of the labels).

I already know how to iterate on the Cells(1,1).

Answer (score 0):

This Loops through all controls until it finds a Label control, then assigns the value of `exWb.Sheets("Macro").Cells(iRow, 1).Value`. Increments iRow by 1, then loops until it finds the next Label control, etc.

```
Dim lbl As Control
Dim iRow as Integer
iRow = 1

For Each lbl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf lbl Is MSForms.Label Then
            lbl.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Macro").Cells(iRow, 1).Value
            i = i + 1
    End If
Next lbl
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I feel like I am almost there, but here is my issue. I need it to fill one of the labels with a value and then move to the next label to be filled. At the end, I need 200 unique labels. The code above seems to change all 200 labels 200 times so all labels are the same by the end.

Comment: The first code included a failsafe, it was removed.  Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: Do you only have 200 labels? cause this code will update all labels.    Unless they were all named "A?" for example, then we can add a line to filter for labels named "A0", "A1", etc with `If InStr(lbl.Name, "A")`  Hopefully this will work for you.